# Increment sub document field in a MongoDb Database

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have this model:

```
{
    id: long,
    items: [{
        itemId: long,
        amount: decimal
    }]
 }
```

edit:
I need to increment the amount value depending on id and itemId.

My query:

```
var query = Builders<model>.Filter.And(
    Builders<model>.Filter.Eq(_ => _.id, xxx),
    Builders<model>.Filter.ElemMatch(_ => _.items, _ => _.itemId == yyy)
);

var update = Builders<modelItem>.Update.Inc(_ => _.amount, incrementalAmount);
```

But i don't know how to execute the query/update.

```
this.Collection.FindOneAndUpdate(query, update);
```

Of course i can't use this UpdateDefinition because i must use builder<'model> instead of builder<'modelItem>, but how to increment the sub property ?

Comment: This is not a "please do this for me" page, but a "I've done this, it does not work, can you help me?" page. Show the people what you did and they can help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found how to increment the sub document:

The query stay the same, and i use the operator $ to update the appropriate array item:

```
Builders<Model>.Update.Inc("Items.$.Amount", incrementValue);
```

For a little bit more complicated increment, Im using the arrayfilter:

```
var caf = new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<ModelItem>(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument("caf.ItemId", new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument("$eq", YYYY)));
var oaf = new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<ModelItem>(new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument("oaf.ItemId", new MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument("$ne", YYYY)));

var query = Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq(_ => _.Id, XXXX);

var update = Builders<Model>.Update.Combine(
    Builders<Model>.Update.Inc("Items.$[caf].Amount", incrementValue),
    Builders<Model>.Update.Inc("Items.$[oaf].Amount", -incrementValue)
);

await this.Collection.UpdateManyAsync(query, update, new UpdateOptions()
{
    ArrayFilters = new List<ArrayFilterDefinition>() { caf, oaf}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just perform an update

```
var query = Builders<model>.Filter.And(
    Builders<model>.Filter.Eq(_ => _.id, xxx),
    Builders<model>.Filter.ElemMatch(_ => _.items, _ => _.itemId == yyy)
);

var update = Builders<model>.Update.Inc(_ => _.amount, incrementalAmount);
```

And then to perform the update:

```
this.Collection.Update(query, update);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, But i can not do this, i have this error:
Can not convert UpdateDefinition<model> to UpdateDefinition<modelItem>

Comment: I updated my answer. The Builder model for your Update needs to be the same as your query. The query was using "model" and the update "modelItem" - They should both use "model"

Comment: thanks for your help, i finally found how to do the update. As the amount property is in ModelItem, i couldn't use your answer. I'm using now the operator $ in the UpdateDefinition